# Swift 2.0 Protocol Extensions on Any Protocol

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

I'm trying to add a method on the Any Protocol in swift 2.0, but I get this error, Non-nominal type 'Any' (aka protocol<>) cannot be extended.

Any idea why am I unable to add a protocol extension to the Any type? What could be a possible workaround to this limitation? My intention is to add a getter called isPrimitiveType that returns true if the object is a primitive or is an actual object.

Comment: what is your actual use case with an example, why would you want to do this?

Comment: this is what Im planning to do,
var isPrimitive: Bool {
 return self is String || self is Bool || self is Int || self is Float || self is Double
}

Comment: Can you give an example of where you would use this in your code?

Comment: I'm creating an extension on NSManagedObject that will take all primitive values from a Dictionary<String, Any> (after parsing Json) and will set all primitive values in that NSManagedObject. It would be nice to have a getter that returns true if the Any object is actually a primitive. For non primitive values like Arrays and such, I'll set them manually

Comment: You should look into a switch statement and put it in your parser - you cannot add extensions for Any protocol

Comment: well I did that filtration in a filter using an 'is' but why is protocol extension on Any not allowed?

Answer (score 3):

As of Swift 2.1 you cannot extend protocols like `Any` and `AnyObject`. Probably in future you can do that.

As workaround you can use a generic global free function:

```
func isPrimitive<T>(value: T) -> Bool {
    return value is String || value is Bool || value is Int || value is Float || value is Double
}
```